# Post variables to php file and load result on same page with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have tried searching quite a bit but can't seem to make anything work.

I am trying to make a form that sends info to a PHP file and displays the output of the PHP file on the same page.

What I have so far:

HTML:

```
    <html>
      <form id="form">
        <input id="info" type="text" />
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Check" />
      </form>
      <div id="result"></div>
    </html>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var info= $('#info').val();
var dataString = "info="+info;

$('#submit').click(function (){
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(res) {
            $('#result').html(res);
                }

  });

});
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

  $url = '/api.php?&info='.$_POST['info']; 

  $reply = file_get_contents($url); 

   echo $reply;

?>
```

When I set the form action to *api.php,* I get the result I am looking for. Basically what I want is to see the same thing in the *"result"* div as I would see when the *api.php* is loaded.

I cannot get any solutions to work.

Comment: What seems to go wrong?

Comment: Is it because you're in a subfolder? `/api.php` goes to the root, then looks for a file named `api.php`. `api.php` looks for that file in the current directory.

Comment: When I originally posted the question, nothing happened at all, and the page would refresh. I added return false; to the click event as Steve suggested, and I also added echo $url; to the php file so that I could see the URL. My new problem is that the url is "api.php/?info=" instead of being "api.php/?info=(whateverinfosubmitted)"

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php

Answer (score 1):

Your click event is not stopping the actual transaction of the page request to the server. To do so, simply add "return false;" to the end of your click function:

```
$('#submit').click(function (){
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(res) {
        $('#result').html(res);
    }
 });

 return false;

});
```

Additionally, you should update the `type="submit"` from the submit button to `type="button"` or (but not both) change `.click(` to `.submit(`

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved part of my problem.  I updated the php file to also echo the url, and it looks like the $_POST['info'] is not being submitted, the url that it echos is "/api.php&info=". Should I be using something else in the place of $_POST['info'] in the api url?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help, I have it working now.

I was doing a few things wrong:

1. I was using single quotes in my php file for the URL and also for the $_POST[''] variables.
2. I needed to add return false; as Steve pointed out.
3. I did not have a "name" for the input elements, only an ID.

Answer (score 0):

I think Your code evaluate `dataString` before it is filled with anything. Try to put this into function of `$.ajax`. The code below.

```
/* ... */

$('#submit').click(function (){
    $.ajax({
        var info= $('#info').val();
        var dataString = "info="+info;

/* ... */
```